# Ubuntu laptop heating with ubuntu except 14.04

Tags: ati, laptop, radeon, overheating

I have hp pavilion g6-2312ax with amd processor and graphic card. On windows I would use "Hp Cool and Quite" to keep the temperatures and fan speed down. But in ubuntu or any other linux version, the laptop heats up like crazy and fan speed is too high.The battery drains quickly.

I found that ubuntu 14.04 and 14.04.1 works good, no heating, thus low fan speed.But once I upgrade it using "sudo apt-get upgrade", it installs new kernel and once again heats up.

So I reverted back to default kernel in 14.04. I want to try out other linux OS's but can't due to this issue. I have tried debian, centos, redhat, puppy and mint so far but still same.

Can any one tell me what exactly makes kernel in 14.04 run without heating problem, so that I can incorporate in other OS kernels.

Laptop core specs : 
Processor: AMD A10 4600M
Graphic card: 512 MB AMD Radeon HD 7660G (Integrated) and 2 GB ATI Mobility Radeon 7670M HD Graphics (Dedicated)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use older ubuntu versions? My linux mint overheats sometimes too (highest was 90c on core 0).

Try using a live cd/dvd of ubuntu 9.04 or 8.04 (my dad has a 9.04 live ubuntu cd/dvd.), Does it overheat?

Comment: Tried older versions like 12.04 LTS, 10.04 etc but still same. however the live cds does run without heating. Not sure why, after installation this problem occurs.

Comment: Try older than 10.04, Does 9.04, 8.04 overheat? Maybe you can use tinycore linux which is pretty small, or "damn small linux"

Comment: What I plan to do is build debian from minimal net install. And use only for multimedia and gaming. tinycore and dsm doesn't serve the purpose of gaming. But debian has same heating issue.

Comment: Currently I am building ubuntu from minimal iso, but debian would have been good.

Comment: @NunoLava1997 says: "Get a cooling for Linux PC's. Does it work?, Also, the temperatures can be a false positive."